# The model in render moder and render are different?

Tags: rendering

This is a bonsai tree in the render scence.
[image]

But when I use F12 to render it.
[image]

It become this?

Comment: Are you using particles or instaces?

Comment: Hi. I use particles to make this.

Comment: could you send your file please?